# What is the best way of implementing hierarchical models in django-nonrel with MongoDB engine?

Tags: mongodb, hierarchy, django-nonrel, django-mptt

Essentially I want to duplicate the functionality of the django-mptt module but in django-nonrel using the MongoDB engine. Does anything like this exist already?

Edit: I know there are various solutions to storing hierarchical data in Mongo described [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/category-hierarchy/) but what is the best way of implementing them in Django?